# how to make a request to my .NET Core App from UWP, with Microsoft Account Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp, office365api

Update

some code on web side

startup.cs

```
        app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Microsoft-AccessToken",
            DisplayName = "MicrosoftAccount-AccessToken",
            ClientId = {CliendID},
            ClientSecret = {ClientSecret},
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft-token"),
            AuthorizationEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint,
            TokenEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.TokenEndpoint,
            UserInformationEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.UserInformationEndpoint,
            Scope = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read" },
            SaveTokens = true,
            Events = new OAuthEvents()
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    var identifier = user.Value<string>("id");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
                            ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, identifier,
                            ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                    }

                    var userName = user.Value<string>("displayName");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
                            ClaimTypes.Name, userName,
                            ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                    }

                    var email = user.Value<string>("userPrincipalName");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
                            ClaimTypes.Email, email,
                            ClaimValueTypes.Email, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

HomeController.cs

```
    [Authorize]
    public string GetInfo()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
```

---

I am able to retrieve user's token with code like this

```
        string MicrosoftClientID = {ClientID};
        string MicrosoftCallbackURL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
        string scope = WebUtility.UrlEncode("openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read");
        string MicrosoftURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" + MicrosoftClientID + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + MicrosoftCallbackURL + "&response_mode=query&scope=" + scope;

        Uri StartUri = new Uri(MicrosoftURL);
        Uri EndUri = new Uri(MicrosoftCallbackURL);

        WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                StartUri,
                                                EndUri);
        if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            string code = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.Replace("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob?code=", "");
            string strContent = "client_id=" + MicrosoftClientID + "&scope=" + scope + "&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + MicrosoftCallbackURL + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(strContent);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token", httpContent);
            string stringResponse = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

but how can i use the token to make a request to API of my .NET Core Web application, which is hosted on azure?

I have tried these

```
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationModel.AccessToken);
            string apicontent = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://{host}.azurewebsites.net/home/GetInfo");
            apicontent.ToString();
```

all I got is html of login page

Any help please?

Comment: How did the API(**GetInfo**) require the authorization? The token you request which contains the Microsoft Graph relative scope means that you can call the **Microsoft Graph** directly. But if your own API require authorization, it still need to authenticate and authorize.

Comment: @FeiXue Thx for you comment, i added some of my asp.net core code here. Anyway i can authorize in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

This Authorize is as same as an normal web application.

If you don't want to authenticate the user when you call this API, you can remove the attribure **[Authorize]** for the **GetInfo**. And if you also have **[Authorize]** attribure for the controller, you can add **[AllowAnonymous]** attribute to specify this action is skipped by AuthorizeAttribute during authorization.

You can refer to [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) about Authentication and Authorization.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it seems irrelevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the Web Api:

Here is my sample method to retrieve friends list from the Api.
Note that there is "Route prefix" attribute - to indicate which resource I would like to retrieve and "Authorize" attribute to demand authentication before calling this method:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Friends")]
public class FriendsController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("GetConfirmedFriends")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetConfirmedFriends()
    {
        using (DbWrapper dbContext = new DbWrapper())
        {
            return Ok(dbContext.GetConfirmedFriends());
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the UWP application you will call this method like below:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Friend>> GetConfirmedFriends()
    {
       //access token eretrieved after MS authentication:
        if (_accessToken == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Access token cannot be empty. Please authenticate first");
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                ObservableCollection<Friend> friends = null;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
                var data = await client.GetAsync(string.Concat(https://{host}.azurewebsites.net/, "api/Friends/GetConfirmedFriends"));
                var jsonResponse = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (jsonResponse != null)
                    friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Friend>>(jsonResponse);
                return friends;
            }
        }

        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling GetConfirmedFriends method: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and code sample, i believe i have a similar pattern just like what you did here. but i cant pass the authentication when making the request to the action from UWP. I am guessing two reasons for that:1. i am not retrieve user token from correct microsoft api, 2. i am not setting up authentication schema in startup.cs correctly